# Can FinancialData really get the data of options?

Tags: curated-data, finance

The "Wolfram reference" says that the function "FinancialData" can get the data of stocks, options and other financial derivatives. But till now, I can't use it to get the data of options such as AAPL option "AAPL181012C00175000" and so on. So please who can tell me what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: The documentation page for [`FinancialData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FinancialData.html) states "FinancialData can retrieve data on US and other stocks, mutual funds and other financial instruments, as well as indices, and currency exchange rates." There is no mention of options. Further, `FinancialData["Classes"]` evaluates to `{Currencies, Exchanges, ExchangeTradedFunds, Indices, MutualFunds, Sectors, Stocks}`